# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileopener2' of undefined

Tags: phonegap-plugins, pdf-reader

I am trying to read a pdf file in my phonegap project.

I have successfully installed `https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2.git` plugin. However when i try to read the file using the function...

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        'file:///sdcard/Download/readme.pdf',
        'application/pdf', {
            error: function(errorObj) {
                alert('Error status: ' + errorObj.status + ' - Error message: ' + errorObj.message);
            },
            success: function() {
                alert('file opened successfully');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

my logcat says...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileopener2' of undefined at line` where i am trying to call the open method..

other logcat errors include

```
Falling back on prompt mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only.

phonegap.js: line 1548: could not find cordova.js script tag. plugin load may fail
```

please help

Comment: cordova.plugins is not available in your script. check if you have included the required library/script and initialized plugin before using it.

Comment: i do have a reference to cordova.js in the html file. however i see a couple of more errors in the logcat. i'll quickly edit the post. kindly check..